# how to set a dynamic $scope variable in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs-scope

I am new to angular.
I have a function where I need to set the ng-show variable to true or false for multiple divs.

The function would look something like this.

```
$scope.setDivFlags = function(divname,isShow){      
  if (isShow) 
     {$scope.<divname> = true;} 
  else 
     {$scope.<divname> = false;}
 };
```

I need the values to be set like this:

```
$scope.div1 = true;
$scope.div2 = true;
```

and so on....

How to pass div1,div2...etc.. dynamically.

Comment: did you try `$scope[divname]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define one variable alone and add multiple `ng-show` attributes like shown below.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Or you can add all the divs to a common parent and then trigger the `ng-show`.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

With angular you can even write the toggle funtion inside `ng-click` like so.

```
<button ng-click="test = !test">toggle visibility</button>
```

which is the same as writing.

**HTML:**

```
<button ng-click="toggle()">toggle visibility</button>
```

**JS:**

```
  $scope.toggle = function(){
    $scope.test = !$scope.test;
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot the last approach of adding toggle like functionality solved my problem!